# Is there a simple way to rotate an image in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am at the very beginning of learning pygame, and I have an image [https://imgur.com/a/t24fNiA], and it moves from side to side. With it being a circle, I want it to rotate/roll a little bit each time it moves.

I have checked online about this, but couldn't really apply it to my own work. so far all I have is `def rotcenter(image, angle):`. I don't really know where to go from here.

```
 if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    xchange = -5
                    # image rotates

                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    xchange = 5
                    # image rotates
```

In place of the `# image rotates`, I would like to call a subroutine which rotates the image by a certain angle.

Ideally it shouldn't go to far because each change in x is 5, but hopefully someone can help me to come up with a solution. Please try to simplify/explain stuff which I might not understand, I have only been using pygame for the best part of about 40 minutes, mainly reading tutorials.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pygame.transform.rotate to rotate an image.

```
def rotcenter(image, angle):
    return pygame.transform.rotate(image, angle)
```

would be your function. You pass it the already loaded pygame image and it returns a new surface that is rotated. So when you want to rotate the image you would do something like

```
image = rotcenter(image, 5)
```

and then blit the new image.

Code I used to test this:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

display = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))

image = pygame.image.load('test.png') #Use the name of your image
rotated = pygame.transform.rotate(image, 90)

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    display.blit(image, (0, 0))
    display.blit(rotated, (100, 0))

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: `image = rotcenter(playerImg, 5)`, `gameDisplay.blit(image, (x,y))`
I have this, but nothing happens? Is the blit wrong, or is there something else?

Comment: does the image not rotate, or not appear at all?

Comment: My image is there, however doesn't rotate.

Comment: Does the x position change by 5 when you press an arrow? We need to make sure that the event code actually gets called.

Comment: The image does move from side to side, but doesn't rotate/roll

Comment: I can't see your full code so I don't know. I edited my answer with the full code I used to test that the rotate works so check to see what is different between mine and yours.

Comment: I don't see what I am doing wrong, in honesty. Here is my full code: https://pastebin.com/wXmgfD0Y It might be obvious, but I don't see what is wrong. Sorry for the hassle!

Comment: update: https://imgur.com/a/YvNDtFL
the image gets crumpled and goes off-screen